# Unable to use Github API with authentication tuple

Tags: python, github, github-api

```
query = "https://api.github.com/repos/rhinstaller/anaconda/tags" 

response = requests.get(query,auth=(self.username,self.token))
response.raise_for_status()  # raises exception when not a 2xx 
    if response.status_code != 204:
        try:
            data = response.json()
            print("data = ",data)
        except:
            print("0")
```

The above code always returns data as empty whereas `response = requests.get(query)` will still work until the rate is exceeded.

What could be the reason behind this? Previously, github APIs used to work fine with this kind of tuple based authentication in Python.

Edit: `print(response.__dict__)` yields :

```
{'_content': b'{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}', '_content_consumed': True, '_next': None, 'status_code': 401, 'headers': {'Server': 'GitHub.com', 'Date': 'Sat, 22 Oct 2022 14:01:13 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '80', 'X-GitHub-Media-Type': 'github.v3; format=json', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '60', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '56', 'X-RateLimit-Reset': '1666449620', 'X-RateLimit-Used': '4', 'X-RateLimit-Resource': 'core', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload', 'X-Frame-Options': 'deny', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'Referrer-Policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'none'", 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With', 'X-GitHub-Request-Id': 'D2F0:13300:1D277E2:1D98791:6353F7A9'}, 'raw': <urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f596e77da90>, 'url': 'https://api.github.com/repos/rhinstaller/anaconda/tags', 'encoding': 'utf-8', 'history': [], 'reason': 'Unauthorized', 'cookies': <RequestsCookieJar[]>, 'elapsed': datetime.timedelta(microseconds=176914), 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'connection': <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x7f596e76cbd0>}
```

Comment: `print(response.__dict__)` and check what's the error is?

Comment: @Msvstl Edited my answer to include `response.__dict__`

Comment: The error says you have provided incorrect credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you have incorrect credentials

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
  
# Making a get request
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user, ',
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'token'))
  
# print request object
print(response)
```

Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/authentication-using-python-requests/